# Signing Jars to resolve Uknown Publisher for Internal Apps

Tags: java, java-web-start, ca, jar-signing

We develop several Java apps for internal use within our company (jnlp). With Java 1.7u40 we are seeing a nasty warning that unknown publishers will not be allowed to run in future java releases.

I understand your jars need to be signed by a trusted CA for code signing ... self signing will not suffice. I don't like the fact that we now will have to pay just to sign our apps for internal use only. I truly must be misunderstanding something. Is there a way to code sign the jars so that they will continue to run with future java releases without the need to pay a CA (Verisign, etc)?

Comment: I view it as an opportunity to instruct users how to examine the certificate critically.

Comment: I described my solution to this problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19878008/2725497

Answer (score 1):

If your company runs an internal CA, then you can issue a code signing certificate from that. Most companies that use Active Directory will also have a CA deployed.

Another approach would be to run a script on all company machines that installs the code signing certificate into the trusted certificates store.

Comment: well, we do have an active directory and there is a way to generate a code signing cert. But I haven't had luck getting it to sign java jar files ... i assumed it was used to sign exe's generated by MSV Studio developed apps. I haven't been able to find clear instructions on how to get it to sign our jars. Unfortunately, no one in our company has used our internal CA to sign jars.